# transformar fechasen palabras a fechas numerica

Tags: python, python-2.7

Tengo que transformar las fechas en palabras a fechas en números

```
21-MARZO-2017 
09-FEBRERO-2017
16-MAYO-2017
```

Las cuales deberían quedar así

```
21-03-2017
09-02-2017
16-05-2017
```

Intenté hacer un *arreglo* con los meses y luego compararlos y reemplazar por el mes por *indice* del *arreglo*

```
 x = "21-MARZO-2017" 
 meses = ['enero','febrero','marzo','abril','mayo','junio','julio','agosto','septiembre','noviembre','diciembre']
 for i in meses 
    if meses not in x
       x = x.replace("MARZO", "index[meses]")
       print x
```

Comment: ¿Qué haz intentando? SOes no es una clase de foro o sitio donde pones tu problema y otro usuario te lo resuelve, debes mostrar tu progreso, lo que haz intentado, etc..

Comment: Veo que ha funcionado. Tienes alguna duda?

Comment: los probe pero tengo un problema con las 2 soluciones en vez de entregar una sola fecha me la repite varias veces pero hace la transformación

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacer esto:

## Código

```
def mesANumero(string):
    m = {
        'enero': "01",
        'febrero': "02",
        'marzo': "03",
        'abril': "04",
        'mayo': "05",
        'junio': "06",
        'julio': "07",
        'agosto': "08",
        'septiembre': "09",
        'octubre': "10",
        'noviembre': "11",
        'diciembre': "12"
        }

    fecha = string.split("-")
    dia =  fecha[0]
    mes =  fecha[1]
    anio = fecha[2]

    try:
        out = str(m[mes.lower()])
        print dia + "-" +  out + "-" + anio
    except:
        raise ValueError('No es un mes')
```

## Ejemplo

```
>>> mesANumero("09-FEBRERO-2017")
09-02-2017
```

## Explicación:

La variable `m` representa un diccionario donde a cada string Mes se le asocia un valor numerico.

Hago un `split("-")` para separar el string en 3: dia, mes y año.

dentro del `try` se busca el par que corresponda al mes que pasaste de parametro y lo guarda en out. Si no lo encuentra da un error.

Al final hace un print (puedes cambiarlo por un return) juntanto el dia + el mes numerico +  el año

---

<sub>Nota: Si tienes alguna duda sobre el código, hazme saber.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

No soy un experto en `python` pero creo que usando una función te sería un poco más fácil y 'bonito' solucionar tu problema:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

# Guardamos todos los meses dentro de un arreglo
months = ["ENERO", "FEBRERO", "MARZO", "ABRIL", "MAYO", "JUNIO", "JULIO", "AGOSTO", "SEPTIEMBRE", "OCTUBRE", "NOVIEMBRE", "DICIEMBRE"]

# Guardamos todas las fechas a convertir dentro de un arreglo
dates = ["21-MARZO-2017", "09-FEBRERO-2017", "16-MAYO-2017", "12-OCTUBRE-2016"]
# Creamos un arreglo vacío para guardar las fechas ya transformadas
newDates = []

# Creamos una función que nos devuelva el número de mes
# buscandolo por el nombre del mes
def getNumMonthByName(monthName):
    # Primero nos cercioramos de que el mes si esté en nuestro arreglo
    if(monthName in months):
        # Si el número de digitos de nuestro mes es '1'
        # le añadimos un 0 al principio (01 para enero, 02 para febrero, etc)
        if(len(str(months.index(monthName) + 1)) == 1):
            currentMonth = months.index(monthName) + 1
            return '0' + str(currentMonth)
        else:
            # Si no, lo retornamos tal cual
            return months.index(monthName) + 1
    else:
        return False

# Recorremos las fechas a convertir
for x in range(0, len(dates)):
    # Convertimos el string de la fecha a un arreglo donde
    # la posición 1 será el nombre del mes
    currentDateSplit = dates[x].split('-')

    # Transformamos nuestro mes
    newMonth = str(getNumMonthByName(currentDateSplit[1]))

    # Concatenamos y agregamos al arreglo las nuevas fechas transformadas
    newDates.append(str(currentDateSplit[0]) + "-" + newMonth + "-" + str(currentDateSplit[2]))

print(newDates)
```

Con lo cual tendríamos una salida en consola como la siguiente:

> ['21-03-2017', '09-02-2017', '16-05-2017', '12-10-2016']